# How to set default value for a INTEGER field of SQLiteDatabase in Anko

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, anko

I know that SQLiteDatabase have no Boolean field, so I need to set a INTEGER field for  DBSettingTable.Status.
I hope to set a default value 0 for  DBSettingTable.Status, but the following code is wrong, how can I fix it? Thanks!

```
import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import org.jetbrains.anko.db.*
import ui.UIApp

override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
          db.createTable( DBSettingTable.TableNAME , true,
                DBSettingTable._ID to INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY+ AUTOINCREMENT,                
                DBSettingTable.Status to INTEGER DEFAULT 0  
        )
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code?

Comment: DBSettingTable.Status to INTEGER DEFAULT 0  is incorrect

Comment: Unresolved reference: DEFAULT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEFAULT` is used incorrectly.

It has signature `fun DEFAULT(value: String): SqlTypeModifier`.

Use it like this:

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
    db.createTable( DBSettingTable.TableNAME , true,
            DBSettingTable._ID to INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY+ AUTOINCREMENT,                
            DBSettingTable.Status to INTEGER + DEFAULT("0")
    )
}
```